# Ubiquity crashes during xubuntu 20.04.4 install on Dell Wyse 3040

Tags: system-installation, xubuntu, ubiquity

I'm having trouble installing xubuntu 20.04.4 LTS on a Dell Wyse 3040. I created the boot disk on a windows machine with rufus. I am able to boot from USB and 'Try Xubuntu'. When I try to install, I am able to select language (English) and continue, then it crashes after I click continue on the keyboard layout screen.
Any help would be appreciated.

Things I've tried:

- `sudo apt-get update`
- `sudo apt-get upgrade`
- different iso version - xubuntu 22.04
- `sudo sh -c 'ubiquity gtk_ui'`

Here is the most recent crash log:

```
ProblemType: Crash
Date: Wed Apr 27 19:10:34 2022
ExecutablePath: /usr/lib/ubiquity/bin/ubiquity
ExecutableTimestamp: 1644317473
InterpreterPath: /usr/bin/python3.8
ProcCmdline: /usr/bin/python3 /usr/lib/ubiquity/bin/ubiquity gtk_ui
ProcCwd: /root
ProcEnviron: Error: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'environ'
ProcMaps:
...
ProcStatus:
 Name:  ubiquity
 Umask: 0022
 State: R (running)
 Tgid:  22776
 Ngid:  0
 Pid:   22776
 PPid:  22771
 TracerPid: 0
 Uid:   0   999 0   999
 Gid:   0   999 0   999
 FDSize:    64
 Groups:    4 24 27 30 46 121 131 132 
 NStgid:    22776
 NSpid: 22776
 NSpgid:    22770
 NSsid: 2752
 VmPeak:      446016 kB
 VmSize:      446016 kB
 VmLck:        0 kB
 VmPin:        0 kB
 VmHWM:   205352 kB
 VmRSS:   124048 kB
 RssAnon:      67512 kB
 RssFile:      56176 kB
 RssShmem:       360 kB
 VmData:       90620 kB
 VmStk:      284 kB
 VmExe:     2644 kB
 VmLib:    37296 kB
 VmPTE:      444 kB
 VmSwap:           0 kB
 HugetlbPages:         0 kB
 CoreDumping:   0
 THP_enabled:   1
 Threads:   3
 SigQ:  8/7106
 SigPnd:    0000000000000000
 ShdPnd:    0000000000000000
 SigBlk:    0000000000000000
 SigIgn:    0000000001001000
 SigCgt:    0000000180010002
 CapInh:    0000000000000000
 CapPrm:    000001ffffffffff
 CapEff:    0000000000000000
 CapBnd:    000001ffffffffff
 CapAmb:    0000000000000000
 NoNewPrivs:    0
 Seccomp:   0
 Seccomp_filters:   0
 Speculation_Store_Bypass:  not vulnerable
 SpeculationIndirectBranch: conditional enabled
 Cpus_allowed:  f
 Cpus_allowed_list: 0-3
 Mems_allowed:  00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000001
 Mems_allowed_list: 0
 voluntary_ctxt_switches:   4598
 nonvoluntary_ctxt_switches:    2218
PythonArgs: ['/usr/lib/ubiquity/bin/ubiquity', 'gtk_ui']
Traceback:
 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "/usr/lib/ubiquity/ubiquity/frontend/gtk_ui.py", line 898, in <lambda>
     lambda: self.dbfilter.start(auto_process=True))
   File "/usr/lib/ubiquity/ubiquity/filteredcommand.py", line 103, in start
     prep = self.prepare()
   File "/usr/lib/ubiquity/plugins/ubi-prepare.py", line 509, in prepare
     self.setup_sufficient_space()
   File "/usr/lib/ubiquity/plugins/ubi-prepare.py", line 534, in setup_sufficient_space
     free = self.free_space()
   File "/usr/lib/ubiquity/plugins/ubi-prepare.py", line 548, in free_space
     devices = proc.communicate()[0].rstrip('\n').split('\n')
   File "/usr/lib/python3.8/subprocess.py", line 1015, in communicate
     stdout = self.stdout.read()
   File "/usr/lib/python3.8/codecs.py", line 322, in decode
     (result, consumed) = self._buffer_decode(data, self.errors, final)
 UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x92 in position 75: invalid start byte
UserGroups: adm cdrom dip lpadmin lxd plugdev sambashare sudo
_LogindSession: c1
```

**UPDATE:**

- adding additional info

lsblk:

```
NAME         MOUNTPOINT LABEL          SIZE UUID
loop0        /rofs                     1.6G
sda                                   28.7G
├─sda1       /cdrom     XUBUNTU 20_    2.7G 487F-EE51
└─sda2                  casper-rw       26G 80431109-4858-bc44-97ea-e24002fefe49
mmcblk0                                7.3G
├─mmcblk0p1                         1023.9M
├─mmcblk0p2                              1G
├─mmcblk0p3                              1G
└─mmcblk0p4                            512M 3492-1BE3
mmcblk0boot0                             4M
mmcblk0boot1
```

**UPDATE 2:**

I pursued the suggestion from Matias N Goldberg below. I tried altering ubi-prepare.py and it did get be past my initial error. However, I suspect that change prevented ubiquity from recognizing my harddrive because after that change, I kept getting ubi-partman error 141 no matching physical drives found. No amount of creating new partition tables or partitions helped.

In the end, I decided to install Lubuntu 22.04 LTS and it worked without any issues.

Answer (score 0):

What's your language?

If I'm interpreting this correctly, there is a device in your system that has an invalid character.

The most likely case being an existing disk partition with a label in a foreign language.

Try changing the name of your disk partitions for something in pure ASCII.

**Update:**

Could you post the output of...?:

```
sudo lsblk -o name,mountpoint,label,size,uuid
sudo lspci -v
sudo lsusb -v
```

## Update

Apparently [this is a known issue](https://github.com/dcantrell/pyparted/issues/76) with Dell Wyse 3040 because your device model says `MMC H8G4a\x92`.

You will likely get better assistance there.

Comment: Updated with the info you asked for. Also, thanks for the suggestion. I will look into that further.

Comment: Posted my updates above